# Blank space not removed when scrollview hidden and height constraint set to 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

Hi I have a scrollview between two buttons on click of top button the scrollview should hide and the bottom button should come below top button ie scrollview height constraint is set to 0 and scrollview is hidden..the scrollview gets hidden but blank space remains.

```
- (IBAction)BusinessBtnTapped:(id)sender {
   if(Flag==0){

    _trackscrollview.hidden=YES;
    _trackscrollbottom.constant=0;
    _trackscrollheight.constant=0;
    _trackscrolltop.constant=0;
    trackView.view.hidden=YES;
    [_businessBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downarrow_small.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    Flag=1;
} else if(Flag==1){

    [_businessBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uparrow_small.png"] 
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    _trackscrollview.hidden=NO;
    _trackscrollbottom.constant=8;
    _trackscrollheight.constant=262;
    trackView.view.hidden=NO;
    Flag=0;        
}  
}
```

Thanks & Regards,
 Roshan.k.

Comment: Try to manage top constraint to first button with the second constraint's vertical spacing & manage constant for top constraint

Comment: _trackscrollheight.constant set nagetive value to work proper like _trackscrollheight.constant=-262;

Answer (score 1):

Add the two buttons and scrollView to the StackView and last add one empty UIView to stackView for filling the empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a vertical `UIStackView` into consideration in your case. Makes the whole thing a lot easier since you do not have to struggle with updating constraints. You only have to hide and unhide the scroll view.